# Calling a function with a list argument in Python

Tags: list, dictionary, list-comprehension

```
test = [
    {'input':{'nums': [19, 25, 29, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14]}, 'output': 3},
    {'input':{'nums': [6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 3, 5]}, 'output': 5}
]

def count_rotations_binary(nums):
    pass
```

How can I call this function with the above list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply provide the name of the list as the actual argument when you are invoking the function. You don't need to supply any expected type in the function declaration.

```
test = [
    {'input': {'nums': [19, 25, 29, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14]}, 'output': 3},
    {'input': {'nums': [6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 3, 5]}, 'output': 5}
]

# This prints whatever you give to it
def count_rotations_binary(nums):
    print(nums)


# Pass the entire list
count_rotations_binary(test)

# Pass only the 'nums' value
for item in test:
    count_rotations_binary(item['input']['nums'])
```